# How do I prove that for any primitive root x modulo p, x cannot equal p-1 for p > 3

Tags: number-theory

How to prove the above? Is it sufficient to prove that $ord_{p}(p-1) \equiv 2$? Thanks

Comment: Do you have any idea or attempts?

Comment: @bitnahian Yes what you have in mind is sufficient

Comment: Is there an easy way to prove  $ord_{p}(p-1) \equiv 2$?

Comment: Multiply it by itself and examine the answer

Comment: I know that, $\phi(n)$ is even for n > 3
and $(p-1)^2 \equiv 1 \quad(mod \quad p)$, therefore it is sufficient to say that the order is 2. 
Am I correct?

Comment: @bitnahian Since here, order $1$ is impossible, the order must be $2$. The argument is correct and shows that $p-1$ cannot be a primitive root of $p$, if $p>3$ because for a primitive root, the order must be $p-1$

Comment: In short, the answer to the question is "yes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $p$ is prime with $p>3$, and $x$ is a primitive root mod $p$, then there exists $n\in \Bbb N$ such that $x^n\equiv 2 \pmod p.$ But $(p-1)^n\equiv (-1)^n\equiv \pm 1\not \equiv 2 \pmod p.$

Comment: If $p$ is composite and $p\ne 4$ and if multiplication mod $p$ on the members of $\{1,...,p-1\}$ that are co-prime to $p$ is a cyclic group (which is not always the case)  then there exists $y$ with $2\leq y\leq p-2$ with $y$ co-prime to $p,$ so $ p-1$ cannot be a generator for the group....($y$ exists because if $p$ is composite and $p\ne 4$ then the totient $\phi(p)$ is greater than $2$ .)

Answer (score 0):

$\phi(n)$ is even for $n > 2$ and $(p−1)^2 ≡1\space (mod\space p)$, therefore it is sufficient to say that the order is $2$.